# Function To Count occurrence of given string

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void check_exist_get_count(string str,char ch)
{
    int counter=0;
    for(int x=0;x<str.length();x++)
    {
        if(str[x]==ch)
            counter++;
    }
    cout<<ch<<" : "<<counter;
}
int main ()
{
    string str;
    cin>>str;
    for(int x=0;x<str.length();x++)
    {
        check_exist_get_count(str,str[x]);
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Without built in function i need to  to count the occurence of letter but i have problem what condition i should use to check which  make for loop not sending letter more than one time
example:in my code i get
input
aaabbc
output

> a : 3 a : 3 a : 3 b : 2 b : 2 c : 1

but Required answer should be

> a : 3 b : 2 c : 1

Comment: What is the purpose of the outer loop? What is the expected and actual output of the code? Please post a [mcve], including the explanation of desired and actual behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just iterating over the string once in your main function, and for every character in that string, again go over the whole string and count how many characters like that are in there.

What you don't do is track which characters you already have counted, that's why you count them multiple times. Don't nest loops (calling your function inside the first loop), but tear those things apart:

One option would be to do a first pass over the string, in which you just build a list of characters that are in the string, something like this:

```
std::set<char> chars;
for (char c: str)
{
    chars.insert(c);    // a set doesn't allow duplicate entries
    // so you don't have to check yourself if it's already in there
}
```

Then you could, in a second loop, call count for each of the characters in the set. That would still be inefficient, though; you can use a map for keeping track what characters are as well as their count so far. Something like this:

Code to compute the histogram of character frequencies then could look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    std::string str("aaabbc");
    std::map<char, size_t> charHistogram;
    for (char c: str)
    {
        // if c not contained in map yet, it's automatically initialized to 0
        ++charHistogram[c];
    }
    for (auto const & p: charHistogram)
    {
        std::cout << p.first << " : " << p.second << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See [code in cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/4nzyk)

Comment: is there anyway to implement this code without using library or built in function ??

Comment: I guess this is a homework assignment then ;)?
sure it is possible, but it gets a bit harder. you'd have to implement something like a map yourself. are you not allowed to use any std:: container type?

a simple version sufficient for this case could be two arrays: one of characters, storing the characters you've already covered; and the second, storing the count of such characters encountered (with matching indexes - i.e. the first entry at index 0 would be 'a' in your characters array, and 3 in your count array at the end)

Comment: @codeling What about `bool seen[256]` lookup table?

Comment: @Quimby that would only address the first part of the challenge - finding which characters are present, no?
If you don't care about memory (with 256 possible entries probably not really an issue in any case), you can also use `int charHistogram[256] = {};` more or less directly instead of the map in above code... and later check which entries are != 0

Comment: Why on heavens earth are you using `map.find`? Please, simply write `charHistogram[c]++;` instead and delete the other stuff.

Comment: wasn't sure it was zero-initialized by default - can't be too careful with these things in C++ if not 100 % sure ;)

but nope, never gonna change to `charHistogram[c]++` instead of `++charHistogram[c]` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another option to add to @codeling's answer. Same idea, but different implementation:

- You can use an array to count the used letters.
  First array position will tell you number of appearances for 'a', second position for 'b' and so on.
- You could extend it to count uppercase and symbols.
- You could also change the `std::array` for a `size_t counts[26]` array.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/GEvKvbY6j)

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::string s{"aaabbc"};
    std::array<size_t, 26> counts{};
    for (auto&& ch : s)
    {
        if (ch >='a' and ch <= 'z')
        {
            counts[ch - 'a']++;
        }
    }
    for (char i{0}; i < counts.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (counts[i])
        {
            std::cout << static_cast<char>('a' + i) << ": " << counts[i] << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I am not sure if case matters. C++ standard solution would be using a map. Anyway +1

Comment: Thanks. I would also prefer a map here, yes; that would pretty much be codeling's answer. But in case the OP cannot use standard data structures, they can easily change the `std::array` into a C array leaving the rest untouched.